# 10 kΩ thermistor failures when connected to thermostat controller units

Tags: thermistor

I have had many failures of these 10 kΩ thermistors when connected to heating thermostat controllers. I have contacted the manufacturer of the thermostat controller units and even they are at a loss.
We have tried several different thermistor suppliers, but this does not seem to change the failure rate.

Here's what I know:

1. The thermostat controller unit's output to the sensor is 5 V DC.
2. There is also an onboard, PCB-mounted thermistor on the thermostat controller unit that never fails. The only difference I can see is that it is mounted to a different PCB than the output terminals for the remote thermistor that often fails.
3. I have been told the connection of the thermistor is not polarity sensitive.

I would appreciate your responses.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is a "failure" exactly? And how are these being used? Have you tried just measuring the resistance of the thermistor?

Comment: The wire diameter is very small and the screw terminals are huge in comparison. How do you attach the wires to screw terminal, just shove them in and hope for the best?

Comment: Do you have the control board schematic or part number?

Comment: What environment is the remote thermistor exposed to? (temperature swings, temperature cycling, moisture, vibration etc.)

Comment: Thanks! please see pic for resistance on a new thermistor (at about 20 degrees C). The reading on the multimeter decreases when the thermistor is failing. Some will read lower than others. The lower this resistance number, the higher the temperature reads on the thermostat controller unit.

Comment: The remote thermistor is set into the floor and also in a protective sleeve so no moisture or mechanical damage should be possible. Temperature swings are not extreme or fast, just between about 10 to 40 degrees celcius maximum.

Comment: We know how it should work but you never indicated why it failed ,Was it too cold or too hot or open cct. or short cct.? These are fragile ceramic disks that should not be dropped.  Next time measure the voltage in circuit and resistance out of circuit. Other than loose screws with oxidation or mechanical , they should be torn down for failure analysis.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, amazing! Each thermistor is tested prior to installation, and all test 100% good. It`s just after they are connected to the thermostat controller unit that they start to fail. Some a few weeks, and some a few years. The terminals on the thermostat controller unit seem to get a good grip on the thermistor wires and no oxidation ever noticed.

Comment: And what is the measurement on a failed thermistor? Also that image is not very clear I must assume that is in kOhms but I can't see the k anywhere on the multimeter display. You also still have not told us how it fails.

Comment: Hi In the pic is 20k ohms on the multimeter.
examples from my testing:
a working thermistor will read 10 on the multimeter for 25 degrees celcius
a working thermistor will read 13 on the multimeter for 18 degrees celcius

a “failed” thermistor can read 3 on the multimeter for 25 degrees celcius.

Comment: @Stev0 - Hi, Diagnosis-type questions are not well-suited to the Stack Exchange format, due to the amount of to-and-fro in comments. The site expects a limited amount of that before it either automatically pushes the conversation to chat, or triggers an alert for us mods to do that. Also, you have been providing new info in comment replies. That's understandable as you're new to the site and the questions are asked in comments. But new info *should* be edited into the question instead. So (a) don't be surprised if this ends up in chat. (b) I recommend applying Kepner-Tregoe "Problem Analysis".

Comment: Take your meter, switch to a 200mA current range and connect the terminals to where the thermistor connects. If the reading is low, switch to 20mA. Don’t forget to switch the meter back to a voltage range. What is the reading?

Comment: Thanks Spehro, I have added pics of that test.

Comment: I don't think there's enough here to figure out what's going on. The current you measured is reasonable, and taking your story at face value, no solid reason for failure. If there is some hidden design defect in the controller that is causing it, we are not going to figure it out without at least a schematic or some clairvoyant ability. Sorry.

Comment: @Stev0 - Hi, (a) Please [edit] the question and explain in *minute* detail (and, ideally, add photos showing) how "*The remote thermistor is set into the floor and also in a protective sleeve so no moisture or mechanical damage should be possible*" as you mentioned. (b) Please add details about what you do when a remote thermistor "fails". Do you have to get access to it in the floor (difficult?) and replace it in the same location & same fixing method? If so, have *any* of the *replacements* failed in the same way? (c) Roughly how many thermistors are installed & how many have failed so far?